# XSLT: Transforming into non-xml content?

Tags: html, xslt

Is it possible to use XSLT to transform XML into something other than XML?

e.g. i want the final *non-xml* content:

```
<Content>
   <image url="file1.png">
   <image url="file2.png">
   ...
   <image url="filen.png">
<EndContent>
```

You'll notice this document is not xml (or even html), but it does have what we would call `<elements>`.

Is it possible, using XSLT, to generate non-xml output?

---

Another example of non-xml output might be:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
   <IMG src="file1.png"><BR>
   <IMG src="file2.png"><BR>
   ...
   <IMG src="filen.png"><BR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

You'll notice this document is **HTML**, because in HTML `IMG` and `BR` tags are **forbidden** from having a closing tag. This contrasts with **xhtml** (the reformulation of HTML using xml) where all elements are **required** to have a closing tag (because in xml every tag must be closed).

---

Another example of non-xml output might be:

```
INSERT INTO Documents (Filename) VALUES ('file1.png')
INSERT INTO Documents (Filename) VALUES ('file2.png')
...
INSERT INTO Documents (Filename) VALUES ('file3.png')
```

---

i can make up any source xml i like, but one example might be:

Source xml:

```
<DocumentStore>
   <Document type="image">file1.png</Document>
   <Document type="image">file2.png</Document>
   <Document type="image">filen.png</Document>
</DocumentStore>
```

Or perhaps:

```
<Profiles>
   <User avatar="file1.png" />
   <User avatar="file2.png" />
   <User avatar="filen.png" />
</Profiles>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `<img />` and `<br />`?

Comment: @KennyTM: HTML forbids closing tags on IMG and BR. It's not that the closing tags are offensive. It's just that proper HTML will not have them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `<xsl:output>` to specify the output format, which doesn't have to be xml, see [this reference page](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_output.asp).

However, if you are outputting html, no modern browser should complain even if you do put the closing tags, so using your example above, i believe all browser should be ok with :-

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
   <IMG src="file1.png"></IMG><BR></BR>
   <IMG src="file2.png"></IMG><BR></BR>
   ...
   <IMG src="filen.png"></IMG><BR></BR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

So not too sure why you don't want to put the closing tag, unless i'm missing something.

---

**Update:** Added example of non xml output

Given this stylesheet:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/filenames">

    <xsl:for-each select="filename">
    INSERT INTO Documents (Filename) VALUES ('<xsl:value-of select="." />')
    </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this input xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<filenames>
    <filename>file1.png</filename>
    <filename>file2.png</filename>
    <filename>file3.png</filename>
</filenames>
```

You get output like this:-

```
INSERT INTO Documents (Filename) VALUES ('file1.png')

INSERT INTO Documents (Filename) VALUES ('file2.png')

INSERT INTO Documents (Filename) VALUES ('file3.png')
```

Comment: @Alan Chan: It's not so much generating invalid HTML that browsers might be able to deal with; it's generating valid HTML so that parsers can handle it.

Comment: @Ian: ok i see. Well, if you use <xsl:output method="html"> to specify that the output is html, and then use <xsl:element> to create the html tags ... e.g. <xsl:element name="IMG"><xsl:attribute name="src">file1.png</xsl:attribute></xsl:element> then the xslt processor should produce the <IMG>, <BR>, etc., tags without the closing tag as required for html.

Answer (score 5):

No matter how you create your IMG tags,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<HTML>
<BODY>
   <xsl:element name="IMG">
   <xsl:attribute name="src">file1.png</xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:element>
   <IMG src="file2.png"></IMG>
   <IMG src="filen.png"/>
</BODY>
</HTML>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output method "html" will cause the IMG tags to not be closed.

```
<HTML>
<BODY><IMG src="file1.png"><IMG src="file2.png"><IMG src="filen.png"></BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: When i reproduce this, the closing tags are included. At the same time, i sometimes might want to include optional closing tags, and sometimes i might not want to. XSLT needs to be able to transform xml into my **desired** output format.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, by using the [**xsl:output**](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_output.asp) element in your stylesheet.